# Mosfet time and PWM frequency relation

Tags: transistors, mosfet, motor, pwm

what is the relation that I have to take into account when I select a mosfet(or a transistor in general) for pwm driving about rise/fall/turn off delay/turn on delay and the PWM frequency? How to compute the maximum frequency?
Thanks

Edit: Thanks to all, but I was searching, if it exists, a formula that can put in relation the situation in which my PMOS can completely charge/discharge without having additional heat, using the time mosfet parameters, and the maximum PWM frequency

Comment: You can have a look and see if there is any good data at the link below. reprap.org/wiki/Gen7_Research#MOSFET_Heat_and_MOSFET_Type

Answer (score 1):

You can rearrange \$i(t) = C \frac{dV}{dt}\$ to \$\Delta t = \frac{C\Delta V}{I}\$ where \$C\$ is gate capacitance, \$\Delta V\$ is your change in gate voltage, \$I\$ is the current the driver is capable of sourcing/sinking, and \$\Delta t\$ is rise/fall time. That will get your close. You want to find the MOSFET with the lowest gate capacitance you can find, while meeting any other specs.

When your rise/fall times start getting to more than a few percent of your PWM period, you need to start thinking about putting in a dedicated gate driver IC, or at least make one with of a pair of bipolar transistors, kept out of saturation.

Answer (score 0):

This might be overly simplistic, but I think that the main factor usually is that a MOSFET is generating a lot of heat during the transition, as there's a voltage drop across it when it's not fully conducting or in cut-off. For example if you have PWM frequency of 1 KHz (2 transitions per millisecond) and there's a 100 microsecond lag in the MOSFET, you might be generating heat for 200 microseconds each millisecond. I think that's the main concern, at least in amplifiers and power electronics.

Answer (score 0):

The three main factors that determined the maximum switching freq are

1) on/off delay.

If a MOSFET took say... 1second before it even started switching you would immediately have a factor with regards to switching freq

2) rise/fall time.

Similar to #1

3) thermal

The higher the switching freq the more losses and at some point you will not be able to thermally manage the device

#3 is usually the driver with respect to switching frequency while #2 is the driver with respect to min/Max pulsewidth